# Plot: 2D potential vortex embedded in 2D uniform flow

Tags: plotting, homework

[image: Figure]Consider a 2D potential vortex (having velocity $u_\theta = c/r$ in a quiescent environment) embedded in a 2D uniform flow (having a velocity of $u_x= U$ far away from the vortex) as below:

Question: For $U= 5m/s$, and $c = 0.5 m^2/s$, plot the velocity vectors for this flow on the domain `{x,-0.3,0.3},{y,-0.3,0.3}`

Comment: Don't you need lots more information, such as the viscosity?

Comment: I don't think we need any other information in this particular problem. I think the matter is the interpretation of vortex flow with ambient flow, and the language of Mathematica plotting velocity vector field following the condition above.

Comment: The basic strategy could be to use `ImplicitRegion[]` to define a region that that excludes the origin then use `VectorPlot` with that region.  If you run into difficulties with this approach, add your code to your question so we can see exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    StreamPlot[
     {
      {5, 0},
      .5 {-y,x}/(x^2+y^2),
      {5, 0} + .5 {-y,x}/(x^2+y^2)
     }, 
    {x, -.3, .3}, {y, -.3, .3},
     StreamStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},
     PlotLegends -> {"Uniform", "Vortex", "Sum"}]
```

[image]

Comment: The vortex component could be written more succinctly as `0.5 {-y, x}/(x^2 + y^2)`

Comment: Yep... thanks.  So edited.

Answer (score 2):

```
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[ 
      {5, 0} + .5 {-y,x}/(x^2+y^2)
     , 
    {x, -.3, .3}, {y, -.3, .3}]
```

[image]